# Cannot Sign for Distribution

Tags: ios, xcode, certificate, xcode7

There are a lot of posts on this topic, but none have been able to help.

## What I've Done So Far

1. I cannot create a new Distribution Cert as it is an Enterprise cert and there are already two valid certs.
2. I cannot access a computer with a valid cert to export from
3. I have created a brand new account and added it to my team and this has not helped
4. I have the updated AWWRDC
5. I have deleted and re-added my account several times.
6. I have trusted the iOS Dist. Cert in my keychain
7. I have uninstalled X-Code and reinstalled. Now running 7.3.1

## Symptoms

The iOS Distribution cert is in my Key Chain but there is no private key.
In X-Code, there is a "Reset" button next to the iOS Distribution.
I can't sign anything for distribution receving this error when archiving:
    No code signing identities found: No valid signing identities (i.e. certificate and private key pair) were found.

This is my 2nd day trying to troubleshoot this. Please help!

Answer (score 0):

You need private key to sign your app. Either you create a new distritbution certificate (remove an old one) from your computer or you ask someone who has access to already existing one. There is no other way around.